# Continuity of a Lebesgue indefinite integral over unbounded interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

We know that if $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-integrable, then

$$
F(x) = \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt
$$

is continuous. But if $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-integrable, it is true that

$$
F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt
$$

is continuous?

Note that now $f$ is defined on unbounded interval, and I don't have any idea to start to think. Any hint will be hellpful.

Comment: Yes. You could write $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^a f(t)\,dt+\int_a^xf(t)\,dt$. Or, you could just prove the result in the same way as in your other case.

Comment: Do you know how to prove the first result?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal If $f$ is integrable, for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ so that $\int_A|f|<\epsilon$ whenever $\mu(A)<\delta$. The result follows from this and in fact shows uniform continuity.

Comment: @DavidMitra: Yes, you are right! Actually my question was for the OP?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Oh, of course. I reponded to the "ping" without thinking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers such that $a < b$. Then for $x \in [a,b]$,

$$F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^{a} f(t) dt + \int_{a}^{x} f(t) dt$$

is a constant plus a continuous function. $F$ is therefore continuous on $[a,b]$. And a function that is continuous on every finite interval is continuous on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how.

> $$ |F(x+h) - F(x)|= \bigg|\int_{-\infty}^{x+h} f(t) dt -\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t) dt \bigg| \leq  \int_{x}^{x+h} |f(t)| dt < \epsilon  $$

Comment: The content is all in the last inequality, which you don't justify. Presumably the OP doesn't know about absolute continuity.

Comment: @TedShifrin: The last inequality is based on a well known fact for Lebesgue integrability!